# npm run start throws an error. Can't find module angular-cli

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm doing an 'npm run start' right after 'npm install'. I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and run 'npm run start' again. However i still get the same error :

Error: Cannot find module
    /root/jenkins/workspace/Quality_Dashboard_backEnd_vmx1376/coc-
    ci/webapp_oden/node_modules/angular-cli/bin'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
        at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! dashboard-app@0.1.0 start: `node ./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --live-reload --host=0.0.0.0`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the dashboard-app@0.1.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 1):

Just install angular cli globally using

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli
```